# Extracting part of a string (for a vector of strings)

Tags: r

```
x<-c("123-12","12-24","6-4")
```

How do I extract the portion of each string before the dash into a new vector?  In this example my result should be equivalent to

```
c("123","12","6")
```

How do I do the same thing, except extract everything after the dash?  I.e.

```
c("12","24","4")
```

For my problem, you can assume that every element of x will have one and only one dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For extracting the string before the dash, replace the dash and everything after by an empty character string.

```
sub('-.*', '', x)
```

For extracting the string after the dash, do the opposite

```
sub('.*-', '', x)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another way, with the added benefit off converting the values to a numeric type:

```
d <- read.table(text=x, sep='-')
#    V1 V2
# 1 123 12
# 2  12 24
# 3   6  4
```

Then we have:

```
d[,1]
# [1] 123  12   6
d[,2]
# [1] 12 24  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `strsplit` and `lapply`:

Before dash:

```
b <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, "-"), function(x) x[1]))
> b
[1] "123" "12"  "6"
```

After dash:

```
a <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, "-"), function(x) x[2]))
> a
"12" "24" "4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
substr(x,1,as.vector(regexpr("-",x))-1)
```